# How can i fetch a parameter in jsonb column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select

I have a table like this

```
| id         | reciever                                     
| (bigint)   |(jsonb)                                      
------------------------------------------------------
|    1       | {"name":"ABC","email":"abc@gmail.com"}
|    2       | {"name":"DEF","email":"deef@gmail.com"}
```

How can I fetch `name where id = 1`

the output will be like this

```
| id         | name                                     
------------------------------------------------------
|    1       | ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `->>` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
select id, receiver ->> 'name' as name
from the_table
where id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, receiver->'name'
from mytable
where id = 1
```

Check out other JSON operators and functions on the postgres documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following:

```
SELECT id, receiver->>'name' AS name
FROM mytable
WHERE id = 1;
```

The `->>` operator gets the text value from JSON data by the given key name.